# What is the name for an object saving a cache of the result of operations as part of requests?

Tags: design-patterns, terminology, caching

What is the conceptual term for a service that will respond to a request for a resource by:

- checking for its copy in a cache
- if it exists and isn't stale, returns it
- if it doesn't exist or is stale, calculating/retrieving it and saving to its cache, then returning it

Comment: i would say a cached or caching repository

Comment: @Ewan that's the repository is, but it's more the particular operation that the repo is doing.

Comment: just a 'get' surely

Comment: If the process I've described is just a caching get, then there is another specific, different process that has its own portmanteau.

Comment: @Ewan it's the read equivalent to a write's "upsert".

Comment: I would just call it a "caching layer" in the repository.

Answer (score 2):

It was Memoise: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization.

This does not refer to caching a get, but caching the results of an expensive function.